# RoR Using break in a YML language file, .html_safe not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-i18n

Hi im trying to get an app working on multilenguage, for some of them i need `<br>` inside some lines ... for this i have achieved this using something like

```
<%= f.label :email_confirmation, t('generales.email_confirmation').html_safe %>
```

This works great in the YML i can have this:

```
 email_confirmation:  'Confirmer courriel <br> électronique'
```

But then i found this problem.. for this i dont know how to use html_safe

```
<%= rate @player, :area_domination  %>
```

I tried :

```
 <%= rate @player, :area_domination, t('generales.rateplayer').html_safe %>
```

and

```
<%= rate @player.html_safe, :area_domination  %>
```

or

```
<%= raw rate @player, :area_domination  %>
```

But the `<br>` is not printing as html.

Comment: What is this rate tag you have there?

Comment: have you tried ``<%= (rate @player, :area_domination).html_safe  %>`` ?

Comment: I just did, =( it dosent work.. =(

Comment: it's unclear what `rate` is. it's also unclear where the html should come from in your examples. you have to put `.html_safe` on every string that get's created that might have html inside. so if your rate method creates new string, it needs to do that stuff in there. raw is a better alternative, as it also handles nil cases.